# Is there a continuum contained in a compact metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am reading a paper by M A Armstrong called "the fundamental group of the orbit space of a discontinuous group". In it, he refers to a theorem which says - any light open map between compact metric spaces has the path lifting property.

I tried googling for a definition of what a light open map is and got that it is a map that preserves open sets and continua. I understand what it means but what is a continua in a compact metric space?

I know what a linear continuum is but how do I know that one exists inside a compact metric space? Shouldn't there be an order in the space for it to have a continuum in it? Is there any other definition of a light open map?

Comment: A continuum is simply a (non-empty) compact, connected metric space, so no notion of order is required.

Comment: Oh I see. I have only learnt of a continuum as a linearly ordered set with the least upper bound property and that between any two elements of the set there is another element of the set.

Comment: @Rise, this is how Munkres defines it, but it's somewhat non-standard. Continuum theory is the study of connected compact metric spaces, more commonly.